# Adding limited Row number SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID   GroupID   Date         Value
1    A         2014-06-01   20
2    A         2014-06-02   21
3    A         2014-06-03   22
4    B         2014-06-01   50
5    B         2014-06-02   76
6    A         2014-06-04   25
7    C         2014-06-01   70
8    A         2014-06-05   29
```

I want to have the following result in SQL VIEW:

```
ID   GroupID   Date         Value     RowNumber
1    A         2014-06-01   20        1
2    A         2014-06-02   21        2
3    A         2014-06-03   22        3
4    B         2014-06-01   50        1
5    B         2014-06-02   76        2
6    A         2014-06-04   25        4
7    C         2014-06-01   70        1
8    A         2014-06-05   29        5
```

But, I want to limit the RowNumber field until 24. If the number reach 24, then it will start from 1 again.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: I can see the RowNumber starts from 1 for each GroupID. Are you wanting to limit it to 24 for each GroupID?

Comment: @Raj, Yes, per GroupID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just set RowNumber Column Value to RowNumber%24+1 then when row number reached to 24 then start from 1

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     (PARTITION BY GroupID  ORDER BY ID)
                      -1)%24+1 as RowNumber,
* FROM Table
```

because row number to start from 1 i minus row number -1 to start from 0

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Yes, that's the logic.

Comment: if you want I can send you sql code  full select query

Comment: Yes, why not... Just edit your answer mate. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **decode** function available in SQL. Once the RowNumber reaches 25, RowNumber starts again from 1.

try executing below query:

select ID,GroupID,Date,Value, decode(mod(rownum,24), 0 , 24, mod(rownum,24)) mod_Val from Table

Answer (score 0):

this code can be helpful

```
with std as (select *,row_number() over(partition by groupid order by groupid,id) as RowNumber
from table1)
select * from std order by id
```